# Why do Shia believe in Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) but at the same time question his honor?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, shia-sunni, battle-of-jamal

I am interested to get the answer to this contradiction which was made by almost all Shia. Actually, I asked many Shia people to explain to me and to solve the following belief contradiction: Do you believe in Mohamed(SAWW) as a prophet? They answered me yes. And  What about Aisha(May God Be Pleased With Her) ? They answered me: She is a wife of our Prophet ? I ask again: Do you love Mohammad (Peace Be Upon Him) ? They said: Sure, we love him. Do you love his wife **Aisha** ? To this, they are mostly in silence or say "No". When I asked the reason for it, they answered : She was a cause and temptation in the killing of Al-Zubair. By the way, they believe in [Battle of the Camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Camel).

May I get an explanation of contradiction in the following question; I ask any of  shia people :
Assume I'm your friend lover to your heart?  Assume I say to you: your wife is a prostitute? What about our friendship? Does our friendship still as it were?

Now the main interesting question to me here is :
**Why Shia think they believe in Muhammad (Peace Be Upon Him) and at the same time they stab his honor**  ?

**Addendum** Aisha, (May God be Pleased with Her), did not betray the Messenger (Peace Be Upon Him) as his wife, because she always followed his path (teachings).

Answer (score 1):

Being a wife or relative of a prophet does not automatically make one a good person or one that is worthy of praise.
In fact if you are somehow close to a prophet and you are a bad person then you will be cursed for that more than those who are known to be enemies from the start.

For example in the Quran it says that the wives of Loot and Nuuh were not on the right path and they were made an example for non believing women.
So did Allah stab the honor of those prophets when he mentioned their wives in this way?

Also the son of Nuuh, who went to a mountain instead of believing and going with his father to the ark, was mentioned in the Quran in a bad way.
Again did Allah stab the honor of Nuuh when he mentioned his son in this way?

Further you you have Abo Lahab, the uncle of prophet Mohammed (peace be upon him and his family), an entire chapter in the Quran curses him and has done so in more than 1400 years.

In Shia Islam people are measured by religion. So if a person is pious, 
religious, and has the correct faith he will be elevated. Sometimes to the point of being one of the prophet's family even if he has no biological ties to them.
For example imam Jaffar Al-Sadiq (peace be upon him) told Saad bin Abd Al-Malek "You are an Amawe from us The household of the prophet." (Al-Ikhtisas page 85)
Also if a person strays away from the path then he is hated and cursed even if he is the son of a prophet or an imam.

Also according to Shia it was Aisha who, along with Hafsa, killed the prophet Muhammed (peace be upon him and his family) by giving him poison (Tafseer Al-Aiashi part 1 page 200)

Comment: But Aicha wife of Muhamed peace be upon him is different totally for wife of Nooh , Aycha  follow mohamed peace be upon him  and she never betray Mohamed peace be upon him